# HTML - image to the left of div

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to display an outer `div` with an `image` on the `left` and another `div` with some text to the `right` on it. I use:

```css
img {
  float: left;
}

div.out {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.in {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/AS%3A272372255162386%401441950014433_m/Wachiraya_Imsabai.png">
  <div class="in">
    Flowers<br>are<br>cool
  </div>
</div>
```

Code works almost fine as shown below but how can I make the first blue `div` extend to the very end of where the image ends? Also, how can I add a 10px space let's say between the image and the text? (And also, is my way of adding `float: left;` to the `img` the best way to display it to the left or is there a better way?)
Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.out {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

div.in {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/AS%3A272372255162386%401441950014433_m/Wachiraya_Imsabai.png">
  <div class="in">
    Flowers<br>are<br>cool
  </div>
</div>
```

> I recommend you should learn how to use flex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [flexbox model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for this. Remove the float and on the outer div use `display: flex;`, and the inner div `flex-grow: 1;`:

```css
#flexbox_container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.flex_item {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <img class="flex_item" src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/AS%3A272372255162386%401441950014433_m/Wachiraya_Imsabai.png">
  <div class="flex_item item_selected">
    Flowers
    <br>are
    <br>cool</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    img {
  float: left;
}

div.out {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.in {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <img src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/AS%3A272372255162386%401441950014433_m/Wachiraya_Imsabai.png">
  <div class="in">
    Flowers<br>are<br>cool
  </div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

If you're looking for the blue box to extend to the end of your floated content, your looking for a clear fix. See the minor change above with the added div with class clr.

-- Edit of all edits --
Realized after doing what you asked... it probably wasn't EXACTLY what you meant to ask. But I got the blue box to extend to where the image ends haha.

Comment: not sure why you edited your original answer to be exactly the same as the one above while still having <div class="clr"></div>, it doesn't make any difference

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, didn't use a code snippet before. Edited it to fix it. -- Double edit, didn't realize I copied the wrong code the second time! You're right, lemme do it right the third time haha.

Comment: Your original answer was to provide a div class clr, which is way different than the answer you have now, you edited it yes, but even if you remove the class clr now, it doesn't make any difference "If you're looking for the blue box to extend to the end of your floated content, your looking for a clear fix. See the minor change above with the added div with class clr."

Comment: @Mindless No worries, I was working on it. I was fiddling, but then decided my post may be a teachable moment to everyone else who is new to floated content, so I haven't updated it to anything "better." I'm doing my best man!

Comment: not a problem, i was just confused, always good to have someone willing to help

Answer (score 0):

> `display:flex` don't support in IE9 and earlier, So i use of other way :

```css
.out {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 15px;
}

.content {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.in {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="content">
      <img src="https://i1.rgstatic.net/ii/profile.image/AS%3A272372255162386%401441950014433_m/Wachiraya_Imsabai.png">
      <div class="in">Flowers<br>are<br>cool</div>
  </div>
</div>
```